# Overlay NestedScrollView over CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, layout, overlap, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I'm trying to make a layout similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK5zl.jpg) one, in which the white area overlaps the image.

I have used app:behavior_overlapTop in NestedScrollView, but when scrolling the white area loses its overlapping position. How can I make it fixed to scroll? I can remove collapsingToolbar if needed.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.TripDetailsFragment">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_trip_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbar_trip_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_image_trip_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/trip_details_toolbar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.TravelJournal.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="60dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                
                <!-- buttons, textviews etc.-->
                
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```